# Is it possible to 'automatically'/implicitly enrich an anonymous function?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
enum Car { Mustang, Camaro, Challenger }
enum Driver { Bob, John, Mike }

trait Config {
  def car:Car
  def driver:Driver
  def collect[O](f:PartialFunction[(Car,Driver),O]):O
}

def canDrive(config:Config):Boolean = config collect {
  //what should 'collect' accept in order to satisfy the following:
  //  (1) maintain the terseness
  //  (2) always have access to values of Car and Driver enums
  case (Mustang, Bob) => false
  case (Camaro, Mike) => false
  case _ => true
}
```

I suppose all enum values can be tucked away into a separate trait:

```
trait AllEnumValues {
  val (Mustang, Camaro, Challenger) = (Car.Mustang, Car.Camaro, Challenger)
  val (Bob, John, Mike) = (Driver.Bob, Driver.John, Driver.Mike)
}
```

But, how would I enrich the arg to `Config.collect` such that when the anonymous partial function is created I have access to everything inside of `AllEnumValues` **without an implicit import statement**

Comment: `enum Car { Mustang, Camaro, Challenger }` isn't valid Scala syntax; are you using `scala.Enumeration`?

Comment: Even implicits are never completely invisible, that would lead to incomprehensible code. Just import Car._ in the scope where you need it, or declare `Config extends AllEnumValues` You're not going to be able to avoid having to import them *somewhere*.

Comment: imports don't scale very well. imagine it wasn't just the two enums that i wanted to make available - maybe functions, or 5 enums. anyway, I'm interested in possible ways of solving the issue with either inheritance or composition, not imports.

Comment: I don't see how having an extra import is a problem - and what do you mean by "doesn't scale very well" - realistically, how often are you going to update this code?

Comment: a method like `collect` would be used a lot through the codebase